# Which visa should I apply for (transit or B1/B2)?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens

I will be going to Miami (USA), then next day to Colombia and while coming back I will be staying in New York for 3 days. Should I apply for a transit visa or a B1/B2 one?

Answer (score 1):

For the outward bound connection in Miami to Columbia, a C-1 transit visa would suffice. However, for the stopover in New York on your return journey, you would require a US [B-2 visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html) which allows for visit with friends/relatives, vacation, sightsee, etc.

A [transit visa (C-1)](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/other-visa-categories/transit.html) is not intended for visits, but rather for a continuous journey through the US, including any layovers for a connecting flights.